# Strange result with cv2 warp Perspective

Tags: python, opencv

I want to extract a patch from an image where I have previously identified the patch using

```
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
```

I can overlay the rect nicely with a polygon

The rect can be nicely overlayd

```
matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
h,w,_= ref.shape
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
img2 = cv2.polylines(img2, [np.int32(dst)], True, (255,255,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

[image: marked rect]

however, if I try to extract the patch using

```
extracted=cv2.warpPerspective(img2,M,(h,w))
plt.imshow(extract),plt.show()
```

the result does not seem to match
[image]

Comment: what are src_points and dst_points in your example?

Comment: @Micka output from knnMatch after a few quality checks

Comment: match between what? If you want to warp to an axis aligned smaller image, dst_points should be (0,0),(width,0),(0,height),(width,height)

Comment: @Micka the match is determined using kenMatch on sift features the corresponding rectangle is shown in the first image. The output -- even if it would be aligned as you said -- would be incorrect as can be seen in the second image

Comment: so which points are src and which one are dst? Can you just print both and add them to your question text? Problem will probably easily be solved afterwards...

Comment: a match of sift features is performed between two sets of points. Onr of them is your input image's features (src or dst in your example?). What is the other set of points? Some kind of template?

Comment: Basically
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

Comment: you should upload your template image and best would be to just print and add the actually used points to the question. Good luck otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found an not so elegant solution myself.

The problem is that I need to invert the rect

```
h,w,_= ref.shape
rect=dst
dst = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [h - 1, 0],
    [h - 1, w - 1],
    [0, w - 1]], dtype = "float32")
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, M, (h, w))
```

which results into 
[image]